# Join two tables made by two different Selects on mysql

Tags: mysql, join, select

Hi Im new to mysql and managing so far, but ran into a problem I would appreciate help with.

I have two tables, BASE, and MAILS

On BASE, there is a column named Date and a column named State, on MAILS, I have a column named Sent_Date.

I want to make a table that compares them so it has 3 columns:

- column 1 should be the dates
- column 2 the sum(case when State = "Contacted" then 1 else 0 end) from BASE group by Date
- column 3 the count(*) from MAILS group by Sent_Date

This is basically to compare if I sent a mail to every contacted row in BASE.
I cant seem to get it with a Join

Im a newbie on MySQL and I have tried many different things but it always fails.
Separately I can make both tables, but I cant join them! Help appreciated.

This would be the two tables I want joined

```
SELECT BASE.Date, sum(case when BASE.State='Contacted' then 1 else 0 end) as Contacted 
from BASE 
group by BASE.Date

SELECT MAILS.Sent_Date, COUNT(*) AS Sent 
FROM MAILS 
GROUP BY MAILS.Sent_Date
```

Both look like I want then to look, I just want them together and cant get the join to work.

Base has many Dates that are not in MAILS (the 'Not Contacted' State)
Sample data as requested:
BASE:

```
Date      State
01/01     Contacted
01/01     Contacted
01/01     Not Contacted
02/02     Contacted
02/02     Not Contacted
02/02     Not Contacted
```

MAILS:

```
Date_Sent
01/01
02/02
```

Desired output from query:

```
Date    Contacted     Sent
01/01       2          1
02/02       1          1
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Please post you best (so far) effort to JOIN results of these two queries ON date fields.

Comment: (SELECT BASE.Date, sum(case when BASE.State='Contacted' then 1 else 0 end) as Contacted 
from BASE 
group by BASE.Date)
join
(SELECT MAILS.Sent_Date, COUNT(*) AS Sent 
FROM MAILS 
GROUP BY MAILS.Sent_Date) on BASE.Date = MAILS.Sent_Date

Comment: What difference does it make it if doesnt work. Do you know the answer?

Comment: Give aliases to your SELECTS and join using them.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it! how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There may be better solutions than this, but this could solve your problem,

```
With contactedTable AS
(SELECT Date, SUM(CASE WHEN State='Contacted' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Contacted FROM base GROUP BY Date),
sentTable AS (SELECT Sent_Date, count(*) AS Sent FROM mails GROUP BY Sent_Date)
SELECT c.Date, c.Contacted, s.Sent 
FROM contactedTable c
LEFT JOIN sentTable s ON c.Date = s.Sent_Date
```

Comment: i did! still dont have 15 reputation so it doesnt change it said!